# How to set the environmental variables in ubuntu to install lua?

Tags: software-installation, environment-variables, lua

Great day guys,I am trying to install the `Lua` on `ubuntu`.Inorder to set the **environmental variables** for `Lua` how can i procede?Thanks in advance

Comment: did you follow any link?

Comment: ya i followed this book,but not mentioned clearly http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Lua-Programming-Kurt-Jung/dp/0470069171

Comment: post the lines mentioned on that book about setting up environmental variable for lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move on to your home directory and then edit the `.profile file`.
Edit your `.profile` file with a command like `gedit ~/.profile`.
Append the following to the end of the file:

```
**export LUA_DIR=/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1**
```

To apply the right changes you can `source .profile`.